# How to call/use one ps.1 script functions, variables and classes to another ps.1 files without using psm1 and full directory path?

Tags: python, powershell

`D:\NoName\testfolder1\test1.ps1`:

```bsh
function restapi {
    Write-Host "Initiating Rest Call"
    $test_value = "1"
}
```

`D:\NoName\Testfolder1\testfolder2\test2.ps1`:

```bsh
Invoke-Expression -Command D:\NoName\testfolder1\test1.ps1
function Invoke-Rest {
    restapi
    Write-Host "Invoking rest call and value of test is $test_value"    
}
```

How I can invoke/import the `test1.ps1` file without giving full path, like we do it in Python:

```python
import testfolder1
from .testfolder1 import test1
```

Comment: First of all, you should use Dot Source in the second powershell to call the first PS1's function. Secondly, if all are functions then you should use psm1(module). Third, In python if you want to do,then change the working directory to the one where ps1 is located. I wont say bad question, but poorly researched. Welcome to SO. Go through [HOW TO ASK GOOD QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell essentially has two import mechanisms:

1. [Module import](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878284.aspx) (via [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-3.0)) either with the module name (if the module is located in `$env:PSModulePath`):

   ```
   Import-Module BitsTransfer
   ```

   or with the full/relative path:

   ```
   Import-Module 'C:\some\folder\foo.psm1'
   Import-Module '.\subfolder\bar.psm1'
   ```
2. [Dot-sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0#special-operators) regular PowerShell scripts, also with the full or relative path:

   ```
   . 'C:\some\folder\foo.ps1'
   . '.\subfolder\bar.ps1'
   ```

In your case you probably want the latter:

```
. "$PSScriptRoot\..\testfolder1\test1.ps1"
function Invoke-Rest {
    restapi
    Write-Host "Invoking rest call and value of test is $test_value"    
}
```

Note that the [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0) `$PSScriptRoot` is not available prior to PowerShell v3. On earlier versions you need to determine the directory yourself like this:

```
$scriptdir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent
. "$scriptdir\..\testfolder1\test1.ps1"
```

Comment: Very much neatly explained. Loved it. :)